# Return a function according to the date

Tags: php, function, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I created a page (TheatrePage) in silverstripe that contains start date & finish date (and the Theatrepages is the children of TheatreHolder)

```
private static $db = [
        'StartDate' => 'Date',
        'FinishDate' => 'Date',
];
```

I need to loop through the first week & last week of these theatre in another page.
(e.g.  a theatre StartDate=2018,11,01 & FinishDate=2019,03,15
if the today=2018,11,05`{$Now}` loop the in FirstWeekPage & if today`{$Now}`=2019,03,12 shown in LastWeekPage)

```
<?php

namespace Project;

use Page;
use PageController;

class FirstWeek extends Page {
    private static $singular_name = 'FirstWeek';
    private static $description = 'FirstWeek';
    private static $table_name = 'FirstWeek';



}

class FirstWeekController extends PageController {

    function InFirstWeek($limit = 99999)
    {   
        if ("StartDate <= Now < StartDate + 7") {
            return Theatre::get()->limit($limit)->sort('StartDate ASC');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far?

Comment: you can see my example in my last edit.

Comment: So you want to get all Theatres that have a start and end date **overlapping** the next seven days?

Answer (score 1):

Your Thatre class is like:

```
class Theatre extends Page
{

    private static $db = [
            'StartDate' => 'Date',
            'FinishDate' => 'Date',
    ];

    private static $default_sort = 'StartDate ASC';

}
```

If you  want to get all Theatre Pages you have to run

```
Teatre::get();
```

This will return *all* Theatre pages, sorted by 'StartDate ASC', cause I defined that as `default_sort` in the class. Cleaner code is always good ;)

Now you want to get *all* Theatre pages, that start in this week. The SQL `NOW()` cannot be cached by MySQL, therefor we calculate it manually.

For calculating with dates we can use [PHP's built in DateTime class](http://php.net/DateTime):

```
$today = new DateTime('today');

// set time to midnight
$today = $today->setTime(0, 0);
```

MySQL format wants me to query in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, so let's create the string:

```
$todayString = $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Now we can get all events that start today by filtering all events where StartDate is greater or equal today midnight:

```
$allTheatres = Theatre::get()->filter(['StartDate:GreaterThanOrEqual' => $todayString]);
```

Next we calculate the date string in a week. Therefor we add 7 days to today's DateTime object: add a DateInterval Object of one week:

```
$inAWeek = $today->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week');
```

But we want to include the whole day, so if it starts at 23:00hrs we still want it included, therefor let's set the time to one minute before midnight:

```
$inAWeek = $inAWeek->setTime(23,59);
```

and generate the string for the query:

```
$inAWeekString = $inAWeek->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Now get all Theatres that are in beween today AND in a week. From a database perspective we need all data sets, where start date is greater than today AND at the same time the start date is lesser than in a week. With SilverStripe's ORM we can filter like this, using [search filter modifiers](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/):

```
$allTheatresStartingThisWeek = Theatre::get()->filter([
    'StartDate:GreaterThanOrEqual' => $todayString,
    'StartDate:LessThanOrEqual' => $inAWeekString,
]);
```

The same works for the end date.

Now we want all Theatres that either start this week OR end this week. For `OR` filtering we need to use [filterAny()](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/data_model_and_orm/#filterany).

```
$allTheatresThisWeek = Theatre::get()->filterAny([
    [
    'StartDate:GreaterThanOrEqual' => $todayString,
    'StartDate:LessThanOrEqual' => $inAWeekString,
    ],
    [
    'EndDate:GreaterThanOrEqual' => $todayString,
    'EndDate:LessThanOrEqual' => $inAWeekString,
    ],
]);
```

Note: This returns a `DataList`, not the actual results, and you can refine it later in your template or another method.